# How to draw points when user clicks on a map

Tags: vb.net, draw

```
    Dim HaveToDraw As New Boolean
    Dim xMouse As Integer
    Dim yMouse As Integer

    Private Sub foo(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
        If HaveToDraw = True Then
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, xMouse, yMouse, 10, 10)
        End If
        HaveToDraw = False
    End Sub

    Sub PictureBox1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseClick
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            xMouse = e.X
            yMouse = e.Y
            HaveToDraw = True
            PictureBox1.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub
```

This code lets the user draw an elipse when he clicks on any point on the map, but there are 2 problems with it: 1 - The user is able to draw only one elipse; 2 - The user is not able to erase a previously created elipse.

So, how can I do that solving these two problems?

Comment: To have multiple points, use a List(Of Point) and store each click in there.  In the the Paint() event, iterate over your List and draw each Point.  To erase a previous created ellipse you can trap a Right click on the Map and check for a "hit" against points in your List.  Even better, if a "hit" is found, display a context menu with a Delete option in it.  Make sure your "hit" takes into account the size of the  ellipse.  You can use a standard point to point distance formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Idle_Mind suggested, you could use a list to store your points, and a `right-click` event to remove the points:

```
Dim radius as Integer = 5
Private points As New List(Of Point)()
Private Sub pictureBox1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        points.Add(e.Location) ' add point on left click
    ElseIf e.Button = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then 
        For i As Integer = 0 To points.Count - 1 ' remove points on right-click
            If distance(points(i).X, points(i).Y, e.Location) < radius Then
                points.RemoveAt(i)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    pictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub


'helper function
Private Function distance(x__1 As Integer, y__2 As Integer, mousep As Point) As Integer
    Dim X__3 As Integer = CInt(Math.Pow(CDbl(x__1 - mousep.X), 2))
    Dim Y__4 As Integer = CInt(Math.Pow(CDbl(y__2 - mousep.Y), 2))

    Return CInt(Math.Sqrt(CDbl(X__3 + Y__4)))
End Function

Private Sub pictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
    For i As Integer = 0 To points.Count - 1
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, points(i).X - radius, points(i).Y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2)
    Next
End Sub
```

I also changed the paint code to draw the circles so that they are centered under the mouse-click.

Comment: I was working on a code to do what @Idle_Mind suggested as well, but it was resulting in a ArgumentOutOfRangeException when trying to remove dots. And now I tested your code, and sometimes it does result in that same exception when trying to remove dots. I haven't been able to figure out what is the specific condition that fires the exception yet, but I think it is when there are more than one dot where the user right-clicks.

Comment: Oh, it was so obvious! We were removing points from a Points list inside a For that used that list(?)! So, when we removed a point from the `points`, the `points.count` would not be the same as the compiler first got in the `For` line, thus resulting in a exception. To correct it, all I needed to do was put an `Exit Sub` after `point.Remove`.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Sorry, I forgot to put that exit in there. Glad it was helpful!

Comment: Great start!...I'd declare a form level variable to hold that value of 5 so you can use it both the hit testing and drawing routines.  Then you can simply change it one place and you're good to go.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, thanks! I implement your suggestion in my answer.